# Can Non-Informative Priors be used to Protect against Omitted Variable Bias/Confounding

Tags: regression, bayesian

I have a dataset of Males. In this dataset, there is a categorical response variable with multiple categories and $p$ covariates. I am interested in understanding the effects of these covariates on a male belonging to one of these categories, and how to predict the probability of a male belonging to one of these categories.

As such, I think I can specify the model like this (Multinomial Logistic Regression):

$$
P(Y=k|X_1, X_2, ..., X_p) = \frac{e^{(\beta_{k0} + \beta_{k1}X_1 + \beta_{k2}X_2 + ... + \beta_{kp}X_p)}}{1 + \sum_{j=1}^{K-1} e^{(\beta_{j0} + \beta_{j1}X_1 + \beta_{j2}X_2 + ... + \beta_{jp}X_p)}}
$$

for $k = 1, 2, ..., K-1$, and

$$
P(Y=K|X_1, X_2, ..., X_p) = \frac{1}{1 + \sum_{j=1}^{K-1} e^{(\beta_{j0} + \beta_{j1}X_1 + \beta_{j2}X_2 + ... + \beta_{jp}X_p)}}
$$

Where :

$$
\beta = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\beta_{10} & \beta_{11} & \beta_{12} & \ldots & \beta_{1p} \\
\beta_{20} & \beta_{21} & \beta_{22} & \ldots & \beta_{2p} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
\beta_{(K-1)0} & \beta_{(K-1)1} & \beta_{(K-1)2} & \ldots & \beta_{(K-1)p}
\end{bmatrix}
$$

**Here is the challenge:** Now, I have a dataset of Females with the same $p$ covariates, but I do not have access to the response variable. Naively, I could just take the regression model that I fit on the males and use it to extrapolate on the females - but I am worried that females might have some different relationships between the covariates and response, such that the earlier model would not be fully applicable to them. Thus, I have a case of Omitted Variable Bias/Confounding.

I was thinking - is it possible to use a Bayesian approach in this situation that could use Non-Informative Priors to factor in more uncertainty into the model parameter estimates, thus allowing for more "realistic" estimates and predictions? For example:

For all $k$ and $j$, a Non-Informative prior could be defined as::

$$
\beta_{kj} \sim N(0, \sigma^2)
$$

Here, $\sigma^2$ is the variance of the Non-Informative prior . I read that we could set $\sigma^2$ to a large value to take this into consideration (i.e. Diffuse Prior).

The posterior distribution would then be:

$$
P(\beta|Y, X_1, X_2, ..., X_p) \propto P(Y|X_1, X_2, ..., X_p, \beta)P(\beta)
$$

Now, I would use some sampling algorithm (e.g. Metropolis-Hastings) to sample from this distribution to obtain all parameter estimates and credible intervals, and hope (???) that this Bayesian Male Model would better extend itself to the Females compared to my earlier attempt.

Is this the correct use of Non-Informative priors?

Comment: This not going to work well: you are saying that you are going to assume females are like males combined with additional uncertainty because they might be different: your results will then be informed by whatever uncertainty you combine into the male results and there is no way to make this uncertainty "Non-Informative".

Comment: Your problem sounds more like one of [truncated/censored data](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/548452) than of omitted-variables; you might want to look into [data augmentation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/43488). Also, if anything, your problem seems to need extraneous information, so what you'd want are *informative* rather than non-informative priors.

Comment: thanks for the feedback everyone ... this was actually my real question: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/637799/bayesian-probabilities-for-estimating-the-percentage-of-donut-lovers ... but it was closed multiple times (I think it was too long). I tried to post a watered down version of my question over here ... do any of you have ideas if in my original question (i.e. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/637799/bayesian-probabilities-for-estimating-the-percentage-of-donut-lovers) the approach makes sense?

Comment: "*Naively, I could just take the regression model that I fit on the males and use it to extrapolate on the females*". Are you trying to predict the outcome category $Y$ for females, or to estimate the parameters $\beta$?